# Is there a way to change the type of a column in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I have a table with sensor data and I'd like to change the type for a column, is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a planned feature and there is an [issue tracking the status](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/257).

You can create a new table and cast column values to another type if this is a suitable workaround:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table AS(SELECT * FROM existing_table), 
cast(long_value AS INT);
```

The [behavior of casts](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/cast#examples) will apply.